# Ruby Devkit install error on Windows

Tags: ruby, devkit

I don't have directories such as Ruby200 and Ruby 64. I'd installed them a few months ago. But I deleted them all.
Now I'm trying to install ruby v2.2.6(86) and use devkit. But there are some errors like "Skipping invalid directory" What do I have to do?

`C:\Ruby22\devkit>ruby dk.rb init`

```
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.0.0 at C:/Ruby200
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.2.6 at C:/Ruby22
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.3.3 at C:/Ruby64
Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.
```

`C:\Ruby22\devkit>ruby dk.rb install -f`

```
[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby200'
[WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby22'
[WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby22'
[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby64'
```

it also makes problem

`C:\Ruby22\devkit>ruby dk.rb install`

```
[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby200'
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby22'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby64'
```

Comment: config.yml may have the wrong Ruby path. In your DevKit folder, open the file "config.yml" and change the last line to reflect the proper folder name of your Ruby install and see if that helps

Comment: I resolved the problem by doing some removes in a registry cleanup tool. Though I resolved it, thanks for your interest. :) By doing as yours I can check the way I've done was right. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DevKit script looks at some Registry Keys that were set during a RubyInstaller installation.

When you removed the other Ruby installations you just deleted them instead of using the uninstaller that came with RubyInstaller. That left the Registry Keys as dangling pointing at deleted registrations.

A registry cleanup tool might be able to pick them and fix it for you, if not you may have to manually clean it up yourself.